# Create instance method in metaclass using partial in Python 3

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, partial

Using metaclasses, I am trying to create an instance method by simplifying an existing instance method. The problem is that partial does not work with instance method. This is a simple example of what I try to achieve:

```
from functools import partial

class Aclass(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def complex(self, a, b):                                            
        return a + b + self._value

class Atype(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        return super(Atype, cls).__new__(cls, name, (Aclass, ) + bases, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        setattr(cls, 'simple', partial(cls.complex, b=1))

class B(metaclass=Atype):
    pass

b = B(10)

print(b.complex(1, 2))
print(b.simple(1))
```

and the output is:

```
13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metatest.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(b.simple(1))
TypeError: complex() takes exactly 3 non-keyword positional arguments (1 given)
```

I have solved using lambda changing:

```
    setattr(cls, 'simple', partial(cls.complex, b=1))
```

to:

```
    setattr(cls, 'simple', lambda self, x: cls.complex(self, x, b=1))
```

but it is ugly and has problems with optional parameters.

I could create these method at the instance `__init__` but I guess it makes more sense, and is more efficient to do it on class `__init__`using metaclasses.

Any ideas how to do it properly?

Comment: @martineau: I am  all for using the python-3.x tag, but I don't see any reason for not using "python" alongside it. Also - would not "python3"  be a cleaner tag?

Comment: @jsbueno: Agreed -- but it won't let me change python-3.x to python3.

Comment: @jsbueno: The tag is python-3.x, I don't know how (if at all) these things are decided. I suspect it could be discussed on meta, and then changed if there is support for it. In any case python3 is a synonym, so you can type it in, it will be remapped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I am a bit unfamiliar with Python 3 method handling yet -
the simplest thing I could think of is rewriting `partial` so that it preserves the first argument from the original call, then inserts the "partial" parameters.

It worked with your example, but it needs testing with more complex patterns.

```
from functools import wraps

class Aclass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def complex(self, a, b):                                            
        return a + b + self._value

def repartial(func, *parameters, **kparms):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kw):
        kw.update(kparms)
        return func(self, *(args + parameters), **kw)
    return wrapped

class Atype(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        return super(Atype, cls).__new__(cls, name, (Aclass, ) + bases, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        setattr(cls, 'simple', repartial(cls.complex, b=1))

class B(metaclass=Atype):
    pass

b = B(10)

print(b.complex(1, 2))
print(b.simple(1))
```

Comment: I think `wrapper()` would be a better -- as in more descriptive and correct -- name for the nested function you've called `wrapped()` in `repartial()`. Just a nit-pick for an otherwise excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `partial`, I'd just define class `Atype` like this:

```
class Atype(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        return super(Atype, cls).__new__(cls, name, (Aclass, ) + bases, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        def simple(self, a):
            return cls.complex(self, a, 1)
        setattr(cls, 'simple', simple)
```

The `__init__()` method can also be written more compactly:

```
def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    setattr(cls, 'simple', lambda self, a: cls.complex(self, a, 1))
```

Comment: Yes, I don't really think a metaclass (or `functools.partial()`) is needed here. Perhaps this was just a simple example that demonstrated the problem, however, and metaclasses are really needed in user482819's actual application.

Comment: Indeed,. I need to create instance methods dynamically based on specific properties of the class using the metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the object returned by `functools.partial()` is a callable object, not a function. So apparently Python doesn't care for a non-function trying to act like one in this context. One solution is to create a function as a wrapper for the `partial` object.

```
class Atype(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        simple = partial(cls.complex, b=1)
        setattr(cls, 'simple', lambda cls, a: simple(cls, a))
```

jsbueno's solution (a reimplementation of `partial` that returns a real function) is good though. I really don't know why `functools.partial()` doesn't work that way; not being able to use it in this context is a surprising pitfall.

Comment: This is a good way to workaround `partial`'s pitfall, but I think my own answer is better ;-) because, for one thing, it has less function-call overhead. BTW, another cause of the problem no one has mentioned so far is that `cls.complex` is an unbound method.

Comment: In Python 3 it doesn't appear that there are unbound methods; `Aclass.complex` is a function.

Comment: It is interesting that when the partial is given as fset or fget of a property, then it works fine.

Comment: I have just found this article from Guido and it is very relevant to this post: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html

Comment: So `functools.partial()` needs to return an object with a `__get()__` method that does the right thing...